# You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression in powershell with excel

Tags: powershell

I have started learning PowerShell with excel and getting null-valued expression error

```
#open excel application

$x1 = New-Object -comobject excel.application 

#open excel to show the result in realtime

$x1.Visible = $true

#open the already existing excel to edit

$test = $x1.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\tushar.v\OneDrive - HCL Technologies Ltd\Documents\test.xlsx")

#to open a specific worksheet

$test2 = $test.worksheets.Item(1).Activate

$test2.Cells.Item(1,1) = "alphatext"
```

Error :

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:9 char:1
+ $test2.Cells.Item(1,1) = "alphatext"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Also , **I am not getting the output in the excel**

Comment: I have had some success using https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would advise to use better variable names, so in a larger script it is clear what every variable contains. `$test` and `$test2` are not really descriptive..

Then for what you have tried:

The worksheet's `Activate()` method does not return an object referencing the activated worksheet as you might think, so you need to first get the worksheet object in a variable and use that to perform the Activate() method.

Try:

```
# create excel application
$excel = New-Object -comobject excel.application 

# open excel to show the result in realtime
$excel.Visible = $true

# open the already existing excel to edit
$workbook  = $excel.Workbooks.Open("D:\Test\blah.xlsx")
# get a reference to the first worksheet in the file
$worksheet = $workbook.WorkSheets.Item(1)
# make this worksheet active
$worksheet.Activate()
# and add content to the cell
$worksheet.Cells.Item(1,1) = "alphatext"
```

Finally, creating COM objects consumes memory, so after your work is done, you need to tell Windows that it can clean up those objects:

```
# Don't forget to quit Excel when done (after saving perhaps?) and to remove the created COM objects from memory:

$excel.Quit()
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($worksheet)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Comment: Hey, great answer, do you know if the memory used by COM objects keeps allocated even after we close PS / ISE if we don't release them?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Eventually, Windows Garbage Collect will release them after all references to the objects are gone (i.e. if PS/ISE is closed), and you never know when that might happen. I always like to make sure myself to release the references as soon as possible so I don't have to worry about running into memory problems. I do the same when creating Forms and use `.Dispose()` on them methodically for the same reason.